# How to JOIN two tables based on certain conditions being met?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, **samples**

```
sample_id   status  member_id
1           pass    2
2           pending 2
3           pending 2
4           pending 1
```

and **votes**

```
vote_id sample_id   member_id
1           1           1
2           1           1
3           1           5
4           2           2
```

Both `samples.sample_id` and `votes.vote_id` are autoincrementing and `samples.member_id` and `votes.member_id` should be joined `where samples.member_id=someUserId`.

I would like to return a result set of samples.sample_id where

1. samples.status is pending
2. The `samples.member_id` did not submit a sample
3. The `votes.member_id` has not voted for a sample

### example 1

For example, if the `member_id` is 1, the result set should be

```
2
3
```

Since `samples.status where samples.sample_id = 1` is not `pending`, and `samples.member_id` submitted `samples.sample_id` 4.

### example 2

If the `member_id` is 2, the result set should be

```
4
```

Since `samples.member_id` has submitted `samples.sample_id` 1-3.

### example 3

If the `member_id` is 3, the result set should be

```
2
3
4
```

Since `samples.status where samples.sample_id = 1` is not `pending`

**EDIT**
Of the three conditions that have to be met, I can meet the first one with the following

```
SELECT * FROM samples
LEFT OUTER JOIN votes on samples.sample_id = votes.vote_id
WHERE samples.status='pending'
```

But I am struggling meeting the other two conditions

Comment: In example `3`, why the sample `1` with `status = 'pass'` is returned?

Comment: @Quassnoi changed, thanks for looking out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  sample_id
FROM    samples
WHERE   status = 'pending'
        AND member_id <> $someUserId
        AND sample_id NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  sample_id
        FROM    votes
        WHERE   member_id = $someUserId
        )
```